# Error Linking Drupal user to edit their Civi CRM profile

Tags: drupal, profile, user-account

I'm attempting to provide a link for members to edit their CiviCRM profile page. I'm using the following code: civicrm/profile/edit?reset=1&gid=N.

When member clicks on the link they received the following error message:

Sorry but we are not able to provide this at the moment.
is not of the type Positive

The following is what is found in the log:

```
#0 /Users/executivedirector/Desktop/BAH/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php(374): CRM_Core_Error::backtrace()
#1 /Users/executivedirector/Desktop/BAH/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Utils/Type.php(358): CRM_Core_Error::fatal(" is not of the type Positive")
#2 /Users/executivedirector/Desktop/BAH/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/BAO/UFGroup.php(298): CRM_Utils_Type::escape(NULL, "Positive")
#3 /Users/executivedirector/Desktop/BAH/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Profile/Form.php(309): CRM_Core_BAO_UFGroup::getFields(NULL, FALSE, NULL, NULL, NULL, FALSE, NULL, FALSE, NULL, 1)
#4 /Users/executivedirector/Desktop/BAH/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Profile/Form/Edit.php(122): CRM_Profile_Form->preProcess()
#5 /Users/executivedirector/Desktop/BAH/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Form.php(543): CRM_Profile_Form_Edit->preProcess()
#6 /Users/executivedirector/Desktop/BAH/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/QuickForm/Action/Display.php(92): CRM_Core_Form->buildForm()
#7 /Users/executivedirector/Desktop/BAH/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm/Controller.php(203): CRM_Core_QuickForm_Action_Display->perform(Object(CRM_Profile_Form_Edit), "display")
#8 /Users/executivedirector/Desktop/BAH/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm/Page.php(103): HTML_QuickForm_Controller->handle(Object(CRM_Profile_Form_Edit), "display")
#9 /Users/executivedirector/Desktop/BAH/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Controller.php(351): HTML_QuickForm_Page->handle("display")
#10 /Users/executivedirector/Desktop/BAH/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Profile/Page/Router.php(108): CRM_Core_Controller->run()
#11 /Users/executivedirector/Desktop/BAH/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(310): CRM_Profile_Page_Router->run((Array:3), NULL)
#12 /Users/executivedirector/Desktop/BAH/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(84): CRM_Core_Invoke::runItem((Array:13))
#13 /Users/executivedirector/Desktop/BAH/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(52): CRM_Core_Invoke::_invoke((Array:3))
#14 /Users/executivedirector/Desktop/BAH/sites/all/modules/civicrm/drupal/civicrm.module(448): CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke((Array:3))
#15 [internal function](): civicrm_invoke("profile", "edit")
#16 /Users/executivedirector/Desktop/BAH/includes/menu.inc(527): call_user_func_array("civicrm_invoke", (Array:2))
#17 /Users/executivedirector/Desktop/BAH/index.php(21): menu_execute_active_handler()
#18 {main}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you confirm what Permissions you have set for CiviCRM Profile and Custom Fields?

Answer (score 1):

To expose a profile to Drupal Users/Members for updating in Drupal - you have a number of options - including out of the box - the Profile Name and Address on /user - when your Members have a Drupal account and are logged in:

hit Hello 'Name' to get to /user
Name and Address is a CiviCRM Profile -> hit Edit to update it

Name and Address profile appears here because in it's Profile setting is has View/Edit Drupal User Account checked.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I have the same setting under profile settings and it's still not appear in the members Drupal role as you have illustrated. :/